# Jagged Arrays as parameters for vba sub

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, jagged-arrays

I want to create a Sub in vba that has an Array as parameter. The following code works:

```
Sub phase1State(ByRef arr() As String)
```

Now, I want that parameter to be an array of arrays, or jagged array, how can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Magic word here is variant. A variant Array can store and Array. And can be passed as param

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Sub test()
    Dim jagged As Variant
    ReDim jagged(1 To 3)
    jagged(1) = Array(1, 2, 3)
    jagged(2) = Array(4, 5, 6)
    jagged(3) = Array(7, 8, 9)
    phase1State jagged
End Sub

Sub phase1State(ByRef arrJagged As Variant)
    Debug.Print arrJagged(2)(2) ' 6
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Arraycheck()
    ReDim Arr(3) As String
    Arr(1) = "1"
    Arr(2) = "2"
    Arr(3) = "3"
    Call parameter(Arr())
End Sub
Sub parameter(getarr() As String)
    Debug.Print getarr(2)
End Sub
```